# If transaction_id is not null join on transaction_id else join on user id - in same join?

Tags: postgresql, join

I would like to do a single left join from table a onto table b on transaction_id

```
select a.*, b.*
from tablea a
left join tableb b on b.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
```

However, there are cases where transaction id on either table is missing, in which case I would like to fall back onto joining on a.user_id = b.user_id. If user_id is also missing then fine, I still want to keep all records from a.

Is there a way I can tell postgres to try joining on one field and if it's missing on either table to then try joining on another field?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 2nd join to `tableb` with the condition that the 1st join did not match:

```
select a.*, 
  coalesce(b1.col1, b2.col1), coalesce(b1.col2, b2.col2), ..... 
from tablea a 
left join tableb b1 on b1.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
left join tableb b2 on b2.user_id = a.user_id and b1.transaction_id is null
```